# New-AzureADApplication RequiredResourceAccess

Tags: powershell-7.0

I am new to Powershell so bear with me if I do not use the correct terminology.

I am trying to use a snippet of code I found in order to register an application and set -RequiredResourceAccess. Everything I find in regarding this approaches it in the same basic way so I wonder if this is an issue with 7 vs 5 as I have run in to. I just don't know enough.

With the following code I get the below error as if it's seeing a string instead of an object. Thought this how I have seen it done elsewhere.

Set-AzureADApplication: Cannot bind parameter 'RequiredResourceAccess'. Cannot convert value "class RequiredResourceAccess {
ResourceAppId: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
ResourceAccess: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess] } " to type "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess". Error: "Cannot convert the "class RequiredResourceAccess { ResourceAppId: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 ResourceAccess: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
}
" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess" to type "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"."

```
$acc1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "62a82d76-70ea-41e2-9197-370581804d09","Role" # Group.ReadWrite.All
$acc2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214","Role" # User.Read.All
$req.ResourceAccess = $acc1,$acc2
$req.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # MS Graph Resource ID

$ccredsApp = New-AzureADApplication `
    -IdentifierUris ("app://{0}" -f $settings.webAPI.name) `
    -DisplayName ("{0}-clientcreds" -f $settings.webAPI.name) `
    -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $false 

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ccredsApp.objectId -RequiredResourceAccess $req`
```

Comment: I am thinking I should try to use Graph for this. The example I am working off of flips between Powershell modules and Graph in a seemingly random way. I feel there is some reasoning behind it but I have no idea why.

Comment: Any recommendations for an active PowerShell community to seek advice?